# Why javascript is called as light-weight programming language?

Tags: javascript

I am sorry to ask this type of question.

but i am extremely confused here,i have gone through another sites to find the answer .

but not getting any proper answer .

Please explain me.

Thank you

Comment: Can you post a link to the source that made this claim? I think a more context would definitely be helpful.

Comment: why is my driveway all wet? these type of questions are hard to answer without any context.

Comment: @wcarroll ,actually i have faced this question in an interview.

it may be a silly question ,but i did not get the proper word to describe them.
so posted over here .

https://coderanch.com/t/631906/HTML-CSS-JavaScript/javascript-lightweight-programming-language   ,

Comment: Because they are not taking the size of the browser into account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a few things this could refer to. Could be the fact javascript is fairly **high level**, **weakly typed**, or **not very complex to write**. Either way, it does seem to be a slightly subjective and vague term.

The fact is is high level simply means it has quite a few abstraction layers that differ it from machine code. C++, for example, is more low level, and getting something done in C++ takes more lines of code, but executes quicker.

Javascript is also weakly typed, meaning you do not need to specify data types, return types, etc. This is good and bad. It ends up making development quicker, but can cause more bugs that are not immediately recognised by the compiler. Also, it can remove reading clarity.

Finally, Javascript is arguably easier to write, and understand, then languages such as Java, C++, etc. It is has less methodologies to go about a given task.

Comment: Thank you ,I noted down the basic reason why javascript is light weight .
Next time I will feel free to answer this question .
i got to know some points ,It is useful to me .
:) :)

Answer (score 11):

I do find this answer from @Elisabeth Robson on [CodeRanch](https://coderanch.com/t/631906/languages/javascript-lightweight-programming-language) pretty informative..

I think this is one of those questions which doesn't have a definitive answer and you're likely to get different answers from different people depending on what they think of as "lightweight".

Here's my answer: I think JavaScript can be thought of as lightweight because (at least up to ECMAScript 5) it isn't a particularly "big" language with many many constructs. It's actually a fairly simple language for the most part. Now, each new release of the language inevitably adds more "stuff" to it, which makes it less lightweight. Personally, I don't like that inevitable march towards more "stuff". I like when languages are lightweight: that makes the language easier to learn and understand.

A related way to think about whether a language is lightweight is: is the interpreter/compiler/execution environment for that language simple and fast? Which is really only possible if the language itself is simple. JavaScript engines have become a lot more complex in the past few years, but the tradeoff is that executing JavaScript code has become a LOT faster. I really have no idea how a JavaScript engine compares in complexity to, say, a Java compiler/runtime so I don't feel qualified to really comment on that end of it.

Another way to think of this is to consider the language "ecosystem": how many libraries and frameworks are built for it? While libraries and frameworks are useful, they can make a language feel less lightweight, because if using those libraries and frameworks becomes a necessary part of working with the language (your employer requires it, or your co-workers, or "everyone is using library X"), then again, it's more "stuff" to wrap your head around. In that sense, JavaScript becomes less lightweight by the day as more and more libraries and frameworks are released.

In conclusion, I'd say that I think the core JavaScript language is still fairly lightweight, but the JavaScript ecosystem is becoming a lot heavier by the day.

Comment: You stole this answer from this: https://coderanch.com/t/631906/languages/javascript-lightweight-programming-language

Comment: Well, we are not trying to invent things in here. We are supposed to give the best answer possible.

Comment: Giving credits to the source is also a nice way to do it ... But still thanks for the answer

Comment: @Gjekask ... It was not my intention to steal anything but instead give the best answer. I did find that Elisabeth Robson gave a good one then I copied it. Thanks for reminding me to give her credit.

Comment: @ShashankSharma thanks for letting me know. I just did it :)

Comment: @MohamedKamelBouzekria As for me I am not blaming ... I see it in positive way, because of your answer I saw it in google a bit quickly :)

Comment: To chime in on Elisabeth's point from above. We might consider JS a 'historically' lightweight language.

Answer (score -1):

Javascript is considered as light weight programming language .One of the reasons, is because it does not have any variable types unlike other languages. In javascript everything is considered to be as an object.